# SSRS report cut some columns in IE8

Tags: sql-server, internet-explorer-8, reporting-services

I have a problem with SSRS in my report layout.

SSRS will cut some columns in IE8 only when I open the report for the first time.

The problem does not appear in FF and chrome.

However, to my surprise , the missing columns will appear when I refresh the report in IE8, or if I go to next page and come back again.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to set you IE8 Browser mode to Internet Explorer 8 not IE8 Compat View using IE8 developer tool.

Press F12 and go to Browser Mode tab.

Regards